# Dotnetnuke Module Javascript Namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have two dotnetnuke Modules with referring Javascript function calling. I wanted to work with this namespace Solution from this Answer [Stackoverflow881515](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript) from Jaco Pretorius, which goes back to this Document: [Javascript Habits](http://appendto.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)

But my implementation is not working. I've been searching for hours, but can't find the problem. If I call the function ns.testfunc from Module1, then it's working. But from Module2 it isn't working.

My Example Code:

Javascript Code from Module1:

```
(function(ns, $ , undefined){
    ns.testfunc = function(param){
        alert ("ns.testfunc, param: " + param);
    };
}(window.ns = window.ns || {}, jQuery));
```

Javascript Code from Module2:

```
(function (ns, $, undefined) {
    ns.testfunc("call from other .ascx");
}(window.ns = window.ns || {}, jQuery));
```

But I receive this error:

> Unhandled exception at line 241, column 9 in
>   http://localhost:10127/mypage
>
> 0x800a01b6 - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: Das Objekt unterstützt die
>   Eigenschaft oder Methode "testfunc" nicht

Comment: i executed your script in the given order and there was no error

Comment: You did it in 2 different modules?

Comment: what do you mean with modules? I just copy & pasted your code to the console and executed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be another problem with one of the modules which also has third party code. I tried it now with fresh modules and it's working. So I have to dive a little bit deeper...